# What is the meaning of 让?

Tags: meaning

Could anyone tell me the meaning of the word 让 (ràng) in sentences like this one: 爸爸让我学开车.

I am not sure of the exact meaning; is it to wish?

I've looked it up on a dictionary but I couldn't figure out the exact meaning.

Thank you very much.

Clara

Comment: 让 means 'allow' or 'let' here

Answer (score 5):

The sentence '爸爸让我学开车' is too short to be certain which meaning of 让 should be assigned here.

- '我恳求了很多次爸爸才**让**我学开车.' - 'I pleaded with my father many times  before he **allowed** me to learn to drive.' (让 = **allow**/let)
- '父亲认为驾驶是一种有用的技能，因此他**让**我学开车.' - 'Father thinks driving is a useful skill, so he **lets** me learn to drive.' (让 = **let**/ allow/ ask/ make)

Consider learning to drive cost money, and often require permission from the parent, "LET" is the most likely meaning of '让' here.

*ongusbongus' answer suggested  '让' means 'ask to'. But in reality, '要' is the more common word for the meaning of 'ask to' compare to '让'.

Even '叫' carrying the meaning of 'ask to' better than '让'

Comment: In Northern dialects, 让 is slightly more frequently used than 要 and 叫 in the sense of "ask", while all of them are common.

Comment: 以现在大多数的情况，通常高考完父母让孩子去学车，是ask或suggest。如果真是穷的不想让自己孩子学车，然后在孩子再三要求下同意了，那也应该用“我爸终于让（同意）我学车了。”

Answer (score 2):

让 in this context means "ask", as in , "Daddy asked me to learn to drive".

I found it surprising that most online dictionaries didn't list this definition, when this usage is very common. I did find it in an extended definition list here: http://www.zdic.net/z/24/xs/8BA9.htm

> (13) 要求 [ask]。如:是他让我来的;她妈妈让她每天练钢琴八个小时

Comment: It certainly *could* mean "ask (me) to" (I'd probably translate that sense here as "want (me) to", but I think there's too little in the OP to make a definitive declaration of that.  Absent further context, I'd say "let" or "allow" is at least as likely.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "让" means "to ask" or "require"

爸爸让我学开车 means "My dad ask me to learn how to drive"

There are other examples:

老师让他不要再迟到了。“The teacher ask him do not be late again”.

Learn more Chinese grammar on this video channel：
http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/demo/hsk_grammar

Answer (score 0):

你可以理解为“let”，和英文里差不多的，翻译成英文就是（My）father let me learn deriveing

Comment: Let是allow的意思，难道他父母之前不同意，现在同意他学车了？那也应该用“我爸同意我学车了。” 无缘无故说个“我爸让我学车。”不通。通常说这句话是想表达他爸想让他去学车。应该是ask 或 suggest。就像“我爸让我下楼活动活动。”难道平时不允许他下楼？

Answer (score 0):

让  ràng allow, permit, yield, concede; as per  UNI definition.

Please use most suitable from above. Any one is suitable. Please remember while writing composition or converting back you have to use same word.so make it simple and do not mess up/ confuse.

Answer (score -1):

让 could mean 'let' or 'ask'.
I wonder if we can learn from each other? I learn english from you and you chinese from me?

Comment: OK. How do you want to do it?

Comment: I wouldn't mind. That would be very useful for me.

Comment: anytime. Do you have a facebook？ my account is JN Lai

Comment: or Wechat? GDjingnan is my wechat account

Comment: hi? have you seen the message?